# Preload nested ng-includes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using AngularJS to "include" html partials in my web app. I'm using a nested `ng-include` for this.

I also have an animation on the outer most `ng-include`. It all works fine. The only problem is that the outer `ng-include` template is loaded first. Then the included HTML file also has an `ng-include` which also loads an HTML file.

The last included HTML file causes the div to suddenly expand in size and that makes the animation look jumpy and weird.

This problem could be solved if all the nested `ng-includes` could be preloaded somehow. Is something like that possible in AngularJS?

The code I have looks something like this:

My main view:

```
<div class="animation-grow-in animation-grow-out" ng-repeat="myList">
  <div ng-include"base-partial.html"></div>
</div>
```

The base-partial.html file:

```
<div ng-switch="myList.type">
  <div ng-switch-when="file1">
    <div ng-include="'file1.html'"></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="file2">
    <div ng-include="'file2.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `file1.html` and `file2.html` contain forms.

But because `filex.html` is loaded with a delay that makes it all look jumpy. So is there a solution for this problem? Can I preload all nested `ng-includes`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use angularjs template caching service to cache your template. When boot strapping your application, put all your templates inside a cache so that it will not make XHR calls for your templates.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache